# Task schedule paths

Tags: marklogic

To clean my database, I try to schedule a task. But I wind up in a path spaghetti.

I have a modules database with `/src/scheduled/cleanData.sjs`
This script contains `require("cleanDataLib.xqy");` 
The scheduled task points to:

- Task path: `/cleanData.sjs`
- Task root: `/scheduled`
- Dbase: `project-content`
- Modules: `project-modules`

Now, the SJS script cannot find the `cleanDataLib.xqy` as stated in the `require`.

I am clueless as to where the SJS scipt is running from now. The task path? The modules database? The SJS script location?

Running the SJS from the query console works fine, then the XQY is used and no errors appear.

Error from log:

```
TaskServer: XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: var cleaner = require("cleanDataLib.xqy"); -- Module cleanDataLib.xqy not found
```

Comment: Please change your setting and try again.Task Path : /scheduled/cleanData.sjs, TaskRoot:"/". I am assuming cleanData.sjs and cleanDataLib.xqy is on the same place '/src/scheduled'

Comment: to make it even more vague, now it complains about a missing Index, so it looks like it ignores the `task database` part of the settings.

Comment: If your module is using any index, it must be added into your "project-content" database. As you mentioned, you are able to run SJS file from query console, please check your selected database. It should match with your schedule

Comment: yes it is part of the content database, that is the strange thing!

Comment: It seems your schedule configuration is right. To check do one thing, change your xqy file and put some generic coding where you don't need indexing and check if it is working. If it is working, change you original logic of xqy file and implicitly include your content database there like xdmp:eval function and share your findings

Comment: your first comment is the right answer, please 'upgrade' the comment to an answer so I can accept it. the other problem has to do with the difference in collation between qConsole and Task scheduled. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your setting and try again. *Task Path = "/scheduled/cleanData.sjs"*, *Task Root="/"*. I am assuming *cleanData.sjs* and *cleanDataLib.xqy* is on the same place '/src/scheduled'